# Magmi product attribute_set changed to default on update

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I'm having an issue with Magmi for the product import.

On the product creation import, the correct attribute_set is set for the products and everything is ok but on the second import with no attribute information (another csv), products attribute_set is changed to Default.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: what version of magmi are you using ?